# Trying to understand the Shunting Yard Algorithm

Tags: c++, postfix-notation, shunting-yard

I am trying to do the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) so I started researching about it. While doing so, I found some interesting documentation which I do not really understand:

```
    // Current token is a number, push 
    // it to stack for numbers. 
    else if(isdigit(tokens[i])){ 
        int val = 0; 

        // There may be more than one 
        // digits in number. 
        while(i < tokens.length() && 
                    isdigit(tokens[i])) 
        { 
            val = (val*10) + (tokens[i]-'0'); 
            i++; 
        } 

        values.push(val); 
    }
```

I do not understand why inside the `while`, the variable `val`is being multiplied by 10 (`val=(val*10)`). Can someone help me understand why the algorithm has to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because otherwise you'd just add the digits. Say for instance you want `123`: you get `1`, multiply with `10` to get `10`, add `2` to get `12`, multiply with `10` to get `120`, then add `3` to get `123`.

If you omitted the multiplication by `10`, you'd just get `1 + 2 + 3 == 6` instead.